# How to convert the datetime object coming from database to string?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am facing an issue where i am fetching the datetime object from database in TIMESTAMP key but when i am transforming that to a string i am getting cannot coerce error.

```
 <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration1" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from DB.db_db1_mule_retry
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="f7e98fea-4c1b-4ff7-86be-e927194d6413" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\list_map.dwl"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    source:  (payload[0].TIMESTAMP) as :datetime{format:"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"} as :string{format:"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"}
}
 
 ]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

The database element is having the value as "2017-10-01 23:23:23.0"

Just an upadate when i am trying to fetch the value in the logger component using

## [Payload[0].TIMESTAMP.stringValue()] i am getting this

2017-03-01 15:39:33.0

Thanks

Comment: what is the type of TIMESTAMP?

Comment: datetime object of sql

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
payload[0].TIMESTAMP as :datetime as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"}
```

Comment: might be `:localdatetime` because of the lack of timezone

Answer (score 0):

payload[0].TIMESTAMP as :datetime {format:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"} as :string {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"}

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting Cannot coerce a :object to a :datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TO_CHAR on timestamp column in database query. After that use as :string with required format.

Comment: Can you please explain better your solution with sample source code?